# jQuery to highlight table row on radio select

Tags: jquery, html, addclass

I have a table (standard markup) with a radio select in each row.  Once the radio is selected I'd like to highlight that .  Sounds straight forward enough but I can't get it to trigger.

Here's the markup:

The Table Row:

`<tr>

<td>some data</td>

<td>some data</td>

<td>some data</td>

<td>

    <label class="label_radio"><input type="radio" name="ame" value="val" /></label>

</td>

</tr>`

This is the relevant part of the JS:
(mods the label to sexify the radio button, that bit works, the  bit doesn't):

```
$('.label_radio input:checked').each(function(){ 
$(this).parent('label').addClass('r_on');
$(this).parent('tr').addClass('.hilite'); //this line doesn't work
});
```

Any ideas?  If I haven't given enough intel, please say and I'll get you what you need.

Greatly appreciated in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The radio's parent isn't actually the table row, it's the label.  use the `.closest` method instead to look up the parent chain until you get to the `TR`.

```
$(this).closest('tr').addClass('hilite');
```

Comment: NOTE: I just edited my answer because the original author was doing .addClass('.hilite') instead of .addClass('hilite').  I rather doubt he meant to do that.

Comment: I am in clearly having one of those days!  Yep, you're right both counts.  My mistake in the '.hilite', I had already corrected that.  Thank you so much - I can't beleive I didn't see the 'parent' issue before asking for help.

Comment: Or he can use .parents() which will find the first hierarchy upwards.

Comment: @Tudorizer: Using .parents() isn't actually the same.  It'll fetch all of the parent elements, even ones past the TR that he was trying to target.  While .parents('tr:first') would return the same element, it wouldn't be as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest way probably, but what if you use `$(this).parent().parent().addClass('.hilite');` ?