# What makes a HTML table row selected?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML table and in a given row I have a radio button and text field.
What makes a given table row selected?  
Do I need to manually set a class when the radio button is clicked?

I've tried just using the

```
$("#myTable tr.selected").length;
```

and it never seems to find it.

I can manually wire up an event to set the class when the radio button is clicked.  However if there is an easier way to accomplish I'm all about learning that way.

Comment: Yes you have to add a class that makes row appear selected

Comment: `$("#myTable tr.selected")` will return table rows, that have class `selected`

Comment: correct! you have to add a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to highlight the selected row by changing its background colour, you will need to set a class on the selected row (and clear that class when the selection changes).  Check this question for more info:  [jQuery to highlight table row on radio select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728331/jquery-to-highlight-table-row-on-radio-select)

If you want to find the row containing a checked radio button, try this:

```
$('#myTable input:checked').closest('tr')
```

Comment: This will accomplish what I need without the need to set/remove additional classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener to your radio button that adds the `selected` class to the table row. Something like this:

```
$('#radioButton').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="image"  value="xyz" checked="checked" />
```